# How to get reminder alert in excel after 5 hour?

Tags: excel, vba

i want get a notification alerte in excel after 5 hour using VB or Macros ?

Comment: And what is the setup? Are you running a lengthy macro during that time? Do you close the file during the 5 hours?

Comment: i want just to get a reminder after 5 hour, in first i will click for exampl in some  button and the chronometre will count .. and after 5 hour the cell becomes red for exampl ..

Answer (score 0):

You can create reminders or notifications in MS Excel using 3 methods quickly and easily:

1. Use the IF function to display a message

   - `=IF(B2<TODAY()+3,"Send Reminder","")`
2. Use conditional formatting

   - Click on Home Tab
   - In the Styles command group select conditional formatting tab
   - Click on New Rule…
   - In the new formatting rule window select ‘Use a formula to determine which cells to format’
   - Under the ‘Format values where this formula is true:’ write the formula given below
   - `=AND(C2<>"",C2<TODAY()+3)`
   - Next click on Format and apply the formatting of the cell and font of your choice
3. Use Excel VBA with a `for loop`. The macro code is given below:

`Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each cell In Range("B2:B100")
        If cell.Value < Date + 3 And cell.Value <> “” Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            cell.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub`

- You can also initialize the formatting in the macro code above with the following line of code under `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`:

`Range("B2:B100").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`

Answer (score 0):

Calling WinAPI from VBA is risky but you may also try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long) As Long

Public Sub AlertMe(dblMinutes As Double)
    Dim idEvent As Long: idEvent = SetTimer(0&, 0&, CLng(dblMinutes * 60 * 1000), AddressOf AlertSub)
End Sub

Public Sub AlertSub(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal dwTime As Long)
    KillTimer 0&, idEvent
    MsgBox "Alert!"
End Sub
```

You may save this one to e.g. Personal.xls and call it this way:

```
AlertMe 300 ' minutes
```